# curve vs 2 curves and correlation

Tags: r, methodology

I've data as follows:

```
DF=structure(list(Y = c(2.14928906795217, 0, 3.93012858139825, 6.14082590843477, 
32.3657647879856, 20.742345290713, 12.0583490565628, 7.41134161362817, 
5.64955983575999, 9.5523958575652, 0, 0), X3 = c(11.6484678352388, 
13.4075041396511, 9.81472130897264, 12.5868638005047, 7.14963862352403, 
6.84409851140762, 7.9620975580154, 5.78816897708643, 7.99036535999652, 
8.78137432971928, 2.85985544940961, 5.16684410647385), O = c(1.43189722145023, 
8.18226983685848, 2.61832634779471, 1.6364539673717, 3.08038393858202, 
10.1823802414239, 16.0670025887403, 15.5180979664557, 21.0775270997474, 
10.1823802414239, 10.0232805501516, 0)), .Names = c("Y", "X3", 
"O"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

The values constitute percentage so the sum(Y)= 100 for example

My assumption is that I expected that there's strong correlation between 'O' in one hand and 'Y' and X3' in the other hand . In other words, 'O' is caused by two factors, 'Y' and 'X3' simultaneously. Is it methodologically correct to make the sum of Y and X3 and to devide by two and test cor(sum,O) ? OR is there any other function that allow me to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I give you a case where the cor(sum,O) is uncorrect.

If O evolves like 1, 2, 3, ..., n

Y evolves like n, n-1, ..., 1

X3 evolves like 1, 2, 3, ..., n

The are linked but sum of Y and X3 doesn't explicitly show this...

(I wanted to put this in comment but i actually can't...)

Comment: And divide the sum by 2 doesn't change anything...